# How much Java should I have learnt before trying Android programming?

Tags: java, android

I have been seeking beginner learning books in Android, and of course found out that I should learn Java first.  So I began studying Java and now I am quite comfortable with objects, classes, inheritance, interfaces, and just moved onto Layouts in Swing as well as Swing Features.  But I am starting to wonder.... do I know enough about Java now?  Can I start programming Android yet?

Of course I can keep going in Java, but have been itching to begin programming Android apps.

Any definitive answer here about how much Java I need to know before Android?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Java is an object oriented language. So if you learn OOP, you'll quickly grasp java: Take the "Master Object Oriented Design" course on http://eliminatecodefear.com - One of the best resources for learning practical object oriented design and development with HW assignments

Answer (score 15):

> *do I know enough about Java now?*

Yes

> *Can I start programming Android yet?*

Yes

> *how much Java I need to know before Android?*

A complete understanding of the basics would be desirable.

Specifically the following topics:

- Declarations and Access Control
- ObjectOrientation
- Assignments
- Operators
- Flow Control, Exceptions, and Assertions
- Strings, I/O, Formatting, and Parsing
- Generics and Collections
- InnerClasses
- Threads

But if you know already the basics ( classes, objects, inheritance, interfaces ) I think you're ok to start.

You don't need to learn specific libraries ( like swing, or others ) because you won't use them in Android.

Comment: Hi, I am from .NET background and I am aware of OOPs fundamentals and the list you have provided in your answer now I am quite puzzled that should i start with learning Java first or should I jump directly into Android development, I have seen few examples and from my initial study(very initial) I did not had much difficulty in understanding  the code and concepts theoretically of course, So I need some advice on the subject from you  If I am going to miss something if I start directly from Android tutorials. TIA

Answer (score 5):

Try it and see - only you can answer that.  If you start and find it difficult, you don't know enough.  It'll actually be a good motivation to continue learning Java.  I'd go for it.

Answer (score 5):

Go give it a try! I find it best to learn programming languages doing real world example, and if Android keeps your interest it is probably a great example.

Answer (score 3):

I jumped right into Java and Android at the same time knowing basically nothing about either. I had about 2 years experience with C doing homebrew for nintendo DS so nothing was really OOP and it was all single threaded.

Since you know what you do of Java, I'd say you'll be fine. The bottom line, is that slow is good. Take it easy, take it slow and don't skip ANYTHING. The provided developers guide is very solid, covers all of the important concepts. An early piece of advice... don't block the UI thread... If you're going to write a game pay special attention to how to create a proper game loop thread. There's really not a lot on that provided by Google (except for SDK example games) but there's information out there.

Answer (score 1):

What you really need of Java is syntax and capabilities. You don't need to know specific API that you will learn with Android anyway.. so I think you can go with Android easily.

Actually you could just learn Java along with Android without any problems..